# Fill a matrix with multido

Tags: matrices

I would like to fulfill a matrix with multido (because I will have tons of matrices to write). I would like to do something like this but that does not work

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,multido,ifthen}
\begin{document}
$$\begin{pMatrix}\multido{\i=1+1}{13}{%
\multido{\I=1+1}{7}{%
1\ifthenelse{\I<7}{&}{\\}}}
\end{pmatrix}$$
\end{document}
```

If someone has a good idea...

Comment: Do you want a 6-by-12 matrix of 1’s?

Comment: It is an example. In my work, the values could change.

Comment: So you want to be able to specify an *m*-by-*n* matrix with constant coefficient?

Comment: Not related: In LaTeX, you should use `\[` and `\]` and not `$$`. See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to).

Comment: Emacs provides a very powerful feature for composing any matrix: you compose the matrix in Calc syntax: [[a b c d] [ef g h]]  and call the calc-embeded function. Calc instantly converts the matrix to LaTeX syntax \begin{pmatrix} a & b & c & d \\ e & f & g & h \end{pmatrix}.
You need to call calc-embedded to revert to LaTeX editing. Since it is easy to repeat any entry any number of times, you can compose a matrix like the one you want very quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\pAutoNiceMatrix` of `nicematrix` to construct whatever matrix you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\begin{document}
\[\pAutoNiceMatrix{13-13}{\ifthenelse{\arabic{iRow}<\arabic{jCol}}{1}{0}}\]
\end{document}
```

`iRow` is the LaTeX counter for the current row and `jCol` for the current column. They are defined by `nicematrix`.

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: The answer is fantastic....for my humble opinion ...For me it is strange that it was with 0 score.